# Cómo hacer que el Randi no considere número?

Tags: matrices, matlab

Hola estoy haciendo una iteración en matlab :

```
>> ensayos=10^6;
>> G=randi([1,4],1,ensayos); // estoy generando un arreglo aleatorio desde 1,4
>> ceros= zeros(1,ensayos);
>> encontrar_1=find(G==3);
>> for i=1:length(encontrar_3)
ceros(encontrar_1(i))=randi([2,4]);
end
```

pero yo quiero que en la parte randi solo considere los numeros 2 y 4 no desde el 2 hasta el 4 osea no quiero que se considere el 3, como puedo hacer eso, estuve intentando pero no me sale :(

Comment: `G=[2 4](randi(2,1,ensayos))` Esto debería funcionarte sin problemas para que G esté formada por únicamente los valores  2 y 4.

Answer (score 0):

Crea un vector que contenga los número 2 y 4, x = [2, 4], luego en el randi coloca 1 y 2 randi([1,2]); esto te devolverá un numero aleatorio entre 1 y 2, luego ese valor úsalo como posición de lectura del vector x.

```
x = [2,4];
pos = randi([1,2]);
ceros(encontrar_1(i))=x(pos);
```